# Is there any legal trouble in a book including a game similar "Jeopardy"?

Tags: copyright, publishing, games

I am writing a book that includes classroom games. Though most are generic, one core trivia format matches  "Jeopardy" in the classroom. The teacher pastes cards on the wall, with questions on the back and numbers 100, 200, 300, etc. on the front, in categories and teams try to answer. The rules are quite similar to the TV game show, but students answer questions instead of answer with questions.

If that were included in a textbook, not using the term "Jeopardy", but having quite similar format for choosing questions and answering, would that violate some kind of copyright?